# How to start time-based score when player taps on the screen to begin the game

Tags: ios, swift

I've been following this solution ([How can I increase and display the score every second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375819/how-can-i-increase-and-display-the-score-every-second)) to add scoring to my game based on how much time has passed. I have it working perfectly; the score stops when the player loses and it restarts back to 0 when the player restarts the game.

However, the "timer" begins automatically before the user taps to begin, and I'm trying to have the "timer" start when the player taps on the game to begin playing (the user first has to tap on the screen to start running, beginning the game).

In my didMove method, I have

```
scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Press Start K")
scoreLabel.text = "Score: 0"
scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 150.0, y: 620.0)
scoreLabel.zPosition = GameConstants.ZPositions.hudZ

addChild(scoreLabel)
```

and in my override func update method, I have

```
if gameStateIsInGame {
    if counter >= 10 {
        score += 1
        counter = 0
    } else {
        counter += 1
    } 
}
```

I figured that by adding the `if gameStateIsInGame {}` to the touchesBegan method, it would start when the user taps on the screen but that didn't work. I tried adding it under `case.ready:` and under `case.ongoing:` but neither worked.

This is what I have at the top of my touchesBegan method.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    switch gameState {
    case .ready:
        gameState = .ongoing
        spawnObstacles()

    case .ongoing:
        touch = true
        if !player.airborne {
            jump()
            startTimers()
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this small issue? I can't seem to figure it out.

### ****EDIT****

Here's the updated override func update method. I got rid of `if gameStateIsInGame {}` and added the `if counter >= 10` statement under `if gameState`.

```
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if lastTime > 0 {
        dt = currentTime - lastTime
    } else {
        dt = 0
    }
    lastTime = currentTime

    if gameState == .ongoing {
        worldLayer.update(dt)
        backgroundLayer.update(dt)
        backgroundGround.update(dt)
        backgroundSunset.update(dt)
        if counter >= 10 {
            score += 1
            counter = 0
        } else {
            counter += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you define gameState?

Comment: @Gismay So, you asking me where I define gameState helped me figure it out! I think I just confused myself with gameStateIsInGame (from the solution I was following) and my gameState. Thank you. I edited my post with the now working update method.

Comment: Try adding an answer with the solution and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Huntress glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

**Simplified Solution**

Added the score counter under override func update.

```
  override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

        if gameState == .ongoing {
            if counter >= 10 {
                score += 1
                counter = 0
            } else {
                counter += 1
            }
        }
}
```